# Similarity measure of two arbitrary functions

Tags: algorithms

Given two arbitrary functions, how can I measure how similar they are? For example:

```
def foo(a: str, b: str):
    return a + b

def bar(a: str, b: str):
    x = a + b
    return x

def fuz(a: str, b: str):
    x = a + b.upper()
    return x
```

`foo` and `bar` are operationally the same, for a given input they produce the same output, and so would have a similarity = 1.

`bar` and `fuz` are very similar and so would have a score between 0 and 1, but closer to 1.

For two arbitrary functions (any datatype input and output) how can I calculate a similarity metric?

Comment: Interesting. However, question of arbitrary purpose gets arbitrary answer, or none at all. What do you want to use that similarity score for in the next steps?

Comment: There is no general solution, since one or both input functions might run forever -- something which in general you can't determine by looking at their code -- and then what should the similarity score be? If you restrict to total functions (i.e. that always return a value in a finite time), then you still need to consider all possible inputs somehow, since otherwise your metric might be fooled into thinking that `f(x) = cos(x)` and `g(x) = if x == 4200 then 123 else cos(x)` have distance 0.

Comment: @j_random_hacker We don't even know if OP wants to just **define** similarity measure OR does he wants to it to always be **computable**.

Comment: We can assume that the functions will always return a value in a finite time. And I want a measure that is computable.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable in its current form.  There might be many possible ways to define similarity, with different properties.  Since you haven't provided us any way to evaluate proposed answers, I don't see how this question can be answered or how we can vote on proposed answers.  I suggest you spend some time thinking about your requirements and what criteria a solution must meet or how you will evaluate proposals, then [edit] the question.